Find the integral of $\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{x}\ln(x)\ln\left(\frac{1+x^2}{(1+x)^2}\right)dx$
How to find the integral of $$\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{x}\ln(x)\ln\left(\frac{1+x^2}{(1+x)^2}\right)dx$$
My attempt- I subsituited $\ln x$ as $t$ which overcomplicated the function.
Any help would be appreciated.

Hint Integrate from $0$ to $1$ and from $1$ to $\infty$. For the second integral let $x=\frac 1y$ and admire.

Remember that, if $A=-A$ then $A=0$ and, perform the change of variable $u=\dfrac1x$

Following Claude Leibovici, let $f(x) := \frac{1}{x}\ln(x)\ln(\frac{1+x^2}{(1+x)^2})$. Then
$$I := \int_0^\infty f(x) dx = I_1 + I_2,$$
where $I_1 := \int_0^1 f(x) dx$ and $I_2 := \int_{x=1}^{x = \infty} f(x) dx$. Substitute $y = 1/x$ in $I_2$, so that $x = 1/y$, hence $dx = -dy/y^2$, hence
$$f(x) dx = f\left(\frac{1}{y}\right) \frac{-dy}{y^2} = -y\ln(y)\ln\left(\frac{1+y^2}{(1+y)^2}\right) \frac{-dy}{y^2} = f(y)dy$$.
Thus $I_2 = \int_{y=1}^{y= 0}f(y)dy = - I_1$.
Therefore
$$I = 0.$$
